# Ajax-запрос не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax("fact_data.json")
            .done(function () {
                alert("success");
            })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("error");
            })
            .always(function () {
                alert("complete");
            });
```

Почему всегда срабатывает fail и always?

Comment: ну посмотрите, что ли, перевод этих слов на русский язык

Comment: @Igor спасибо, перевод этих слов знаком, но непонятен сам факт ошибки, если файл json лежит в той же папке, да и написан правильно

Comment: в Ваших анонимных функциях добавьте `console.log(this);` и исследуйте, что будет выведено в консоль

Comment: Вы должны спрашивать не у нас а у Консоли, вкладки Network. Там будет скорее всего красным выделена загрузка вашего файла и внутри описано что он 404 NotFound. Тут есть несколько факторов, как именно вы запускаете ваш скрипт, запускаете ли вы при этом сервер, или просто создали html файл открыли и написали скрипт

Comment: И кроме просмотра запроса во вкладке Network стоит проанализировать содержимое переменных, передаваемых в `.fail`-функцию. С тем, что передаётся в функцию, можно ознакомиться в [документации](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Если это браузер, то у него нет доступа к локальной файловой системе. Можно попробовать сделать что то типа `'file:///full_path_to_fact_data.json'` но это врятли поможет из-за политики безопасности.

Comment: В хроме можно добавить флаг --allow-file-access-from-files